# What's wrong with my SQL-EXCEPT-Operator?

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1064, sql-except

When I select "BookID" from my tables "Stats" and "Book" I get desired results each like:

```
MariaDB [db1]> SELECT BookID From Book WHERE Author = 'AuthorX';
+--------+
| BookID |
+--------+
|   1003 |
+--------+


MariaDB [db1]> SELECT BookID From Stats WHERE BookID >= 1000;
+--------+
| BookID |
+--------+
|   1010 |
|   1005 |
|   1003 |
+--------+
```

But when I try to use the EXCEPT-operator, I get an error

```
MariaDB [db1]> (SELECT BookID From Stats WHERE BookID >= 1000)
     -> EXCEPT
     -> (SELECT BookID From Book WHERE Author = 'AuthorX');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXCEPT (SELECT BookID From Book WHERE Author = 'AuthorX')' at line 1
```

What I hoped to be the output:

```
+--------+
| BookID |
+--------+
|   1010 |
|   1005 |
+--------+
```

What am I doing wrong?
I tried with and without bracket, but got no idea, what to try next?

**EDIT**: Try with NOT IN

```
SELECT BookID From Stats WHERE BookID >= 1000 NOT IN  
(SELECT BookID From Book WHERE Author = 'AuthorX');
```

yields

```
+--------+
| BookID |
+--------+
|      3 |
|   1010 |
|   1005 |
|   1003 |
+--------+
```

**EDIT2**: "AND BookID NOT IN" for EXCEPT works

**Still would love to know why EXCEPT doesn't**

**EDIT3**: The Examples from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/except/ do work…

**EDIT4**: MariaDB Vers<10.3 does not have EXCEPT <del>seems to be</del> is the answer.

*Still wonder why the examples work…*

Comment: …without brackets the same
    MariaDB [db1]> SELECT BookID From Stats WHERE BookID >= 1000
     -> EXCEPT
     -> SELECT BookID From Book WHERE Author = 'AuthorX';
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXCEPT SELECT BookID From Buch WHERE Author = 'AuthorX'' at line 1

Comment: In the link @MatBaillie posted, it says `except` was introduced in 10.3.0. What version do you use?

Comment: @HoneyBadger - Good Spot.

Comment: ./mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.29-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
…hmmm maybe it's that then

Comment: @kai-dj I'm surprised your `NOT IN ()` even executed.  It should be `AND BookID NOT IN ()`

Comment: Still strange result - 1003 still in 3 added to list (?) [while that 3 might come from some were - i shortened the tables to show here]

Comment: @kai-dj - put the `AND BookID` in where it should be, and see if that fixes it, at present I have no idea what that even means, never mind why it executes.  *(Good luck, I'm off home for the day now...)*

Comment: @MatBailie thx for your help so far :)

Comment: @MatBailie could u turn your NOT IN comment into answer, so I can choose as solution?

Comment: `EXCEPT was introduced in MariaDB 10.3.0.`. Does this answer the _Still would love to know why EXCEPT doesn't_ part?

Comment: @SalmanA Isn't the version regarding SQL-version, not MariaDB-version? (also EXCEPT does work with the examples on the mariadb-hp)

Comment: Answer already has NOT IN as one option :)

Comment: @MatBailie oh ye - sorry my head's starting to hurt ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the brackets.

It looks "nicer" on three lines...

```
SELECT `BookID` From `Stats` WHERE `BookID` >= 1000
EXCEPT
SELECT `BookID` From `Book`  WHERE `Author`  = 'AuthorX'
```

It's much the same as you may see in `UNION ALL`...

```
SELECT BookID From Book WHERE Title LIKE 'Harry Potter%'
UNION ALL
SELECT BookID From Book WHERE Author LIKE '%Toklien%'
```

***EDIT***:

Or just try an alternative expression *(If on an older version of MariaDB)*...

```
SELECT BookID
  FROM Book
 WHERE BookID >= 1000
   AND BookID NOT IN (SELECT BookID
                        FROM Book
                       WHERE Author = 'AuthorX'
                     )
```

Or...

```
SELECT BookID
  FROM Book
 WHERE BookID >= 1000
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM Book  lookup
                    WHERE lookup.Author = 'AuthorX'
                      AND lookup.BookID = Book.BookID
                  )
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT BookID FROM Book WHERE BookID >= 1000
)
  high_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT BookID FROM Book WHERE Author = 'AuthorX'
)
  target_author
    ON target_author.BookID = high_id.BookID
WHERE
  target_author.BookID IS NULL
```

Comment: Then you have some other issue on another line somewhere...  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/except/  *(Try running `;` on it's own, then try your query again with an `;` at the end of it.)*

Comment: that's the only line…

Comment: Did you even try it?  *(just in case there is something else hanging around by accident...)*

Comment: Did both – same result

Comment: What do you get when just running the first half *(before the except)*?

Comment: …the result I desired - as shown in first part of my question

Comment: …both SELECT yielt the right output, just EXCEPT doesn't